# Concealing relatively small objects on my person

Tags: clothing, jewelry

I'm not sure this is 100% appropriate for this site since it isn't quite an everyday problem, but here goes.

Let's say that I have this special piece of jewelry that I have to show to the doorman of the secret organization I'm in, in order to enter the hideout. It is a 5×8×1 cm (2×3×0.4 inch) aluminium rectangle with our logo carved into it.

I need to carry it on me (everyday maybe), but, at the same time, nobody must see it. I need to conceal it in such a way that:

- It (or clues that might lead to it, like a necklace chain if I were to wear it as a necklace) is **completely hidden/hidden in plain sight** while I am wearing a **regular outfit**. For our purpose let's say *shirt and jeans*. It's perfectly fine if I can't hide it while in my underwear.
- I can **access it relatively easily** and quickly. I don't want any awkward situations with the doorman.
- It **must be safe** - both from pickpockets and accidents (someone bumps into me, I trip and fall etc.)

So how should I go about this?

**PS:** Both *in clothes* and *in body* hiding places work, as long as they abide the three rules.

**PPS:** No. Having the outline of the object show trough my shirt without any camouflage is not acceptable.

Comment: It would really help if we knew what object you're try to find, hiding a card is not the same as hiding a (let's say) a knife

Comment: Unless you're able to better describe (or name) the specific object you're trying to hide and why, I'm afraid we'll be playing this *"Does my answer fit?"* game until someone guesses right.  I already had to invalidate one answer based on a wrong guess, so if you can clarify the question, please feel free to 'flag' to reopen. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have changed it and now it should be answerable.

Comment: @donut "in body" as in store it anywhere?

Comment: @Kiwi Yes as long as it fits the 3 conditions. Preferably not too gross of a place but that's not a necessity. The doorman doesn't have to touch it, only see it.

Comment: @donut would an implant suffice?

Comment: @Kiwi can I take it out easily?

Comment: @donut oh haha nevermind

Comment: @Kiwi I guess that opening my shirt to reveal my chest implant would work though. Even if I can't take it out, the doorman can still see it, so it's all good. Body modifications wouldn't be my first choice though but, if need be, they are acceptable.

Comment: @donut Then I will write a 2nd answer as body mods

Comment: A belt buckle maybe.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell from your 'nym if you are a male or female. If you are a female just stick it in your bra. I know a lot of girls who will store their phones in there and they don't find it awkward.

Comment: That's a nice (and quite popular in movies) idea I haven't thought of. I'm a guy but I guess I could be the weird drag queen of my secret club if I have too.

Answer (score 3):

**Idea**

1. Make an armband out of something thin and strong (even a sock that has had the toe part cut off can work *see image*) and wear it on your bicep.
   [image: Sock on bicep]
2. Make a pocket on the armband. The location of the pocket should be between your arm and torso.
   **OR**
   if you are using the sock idea, you can roll it up a bit and use that as the pocket.
3. Connect a chain to the object and attach the chain to the armband.
   **OR**
   You can tie the chain around the armband.
4. Place object in pocket of armband. Wear shirt over armband.

**How to use**
 - *Appear at door and reach into the neck of your shirt and pull out object.*
 - *After entry, while walking place back in armband pocket (including chain, it will look like you have an itch)*

**Tip: Wear 1 on each arm to hide the indifference of your arms if it stands out alot**

PS. Works best with long sleeves or vests/hoodies/coats.
PSS. You can make one for your thigh

Comment: This is a great idea but might be a bit problematic during summer. I guess an alternative might be to do the same thing but on my thigh/around the knee and make a hole on the inside of my pants pocket to reach it.

Comment: @donut Great idea! I would keep it on the thigh to be honest, you want it concealed and not let anyone know you have something there. Unless you use a knee brace, you might be able to do something with that. Also maybe you could something with some thiner marterial that is still quite strong (thinking something like a pantyhose or something), so it won't be so hot

Answer (score 2):

Your given dimensions sound *almost* like a representation of a [Space Odyssey Monolith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monolith_%28Space_Odyssey%29) (1×4×9, or 1²×2²×3²). Is your secret society perhaps the Arthur C. Clarke Fan Club?  :-)

Joking aside, an object of the size you described would perhaps be of the size of a [key fob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keychain#Key_fob). I think it would be easy to simply add it to a key ring, perhaps with some cover like a leather or plastic sheath (perhaps with a car maker's logo), if camouflage is deemed necessary. Which leaves the problem of pickpocketing. What if you attach the key ring, or simply the token itself, to your clothing with a sufficiently strong chain? Either the normal devices that people use for their keys/wallets (unsightly), or more clandestinely: pinned to the inside of you pocket with something like a safety pin?

A related idea is how gentlemen used to secure their pocket watches to their vests, which has gone out of fashion (except apparently in steampunk subculture). Around a decade ago I visited Switzerland and in a watch shop saw various models of wristwatch-sized pocket watches (both in a pocket watch housing, and mounted onto a leather backing instead of a wristband) that were apparently in fashion with some motorcyclists (carried in little denim "5th pocket"). So you could get away with disguising your token in such a housing (and affecting some eccentricity).

In a stretch it could also be disguised as a (non-functional) smart watch. Flip up the face to reveal the token.

I for one however am appalled that a society would use such an antiquated and still easy-to-steal security device (or they could at least have made it out of tungsten, titanium, cobalt, platinum, or some such). As 007 showed us in Spectre, even a small innocuous ring with an engraved octopus can still be pulled off its newly-deceased owner and used to gain entrance to the highest level meeting. Not a good idea. Perhaps your society should consider something more modern like a [subdermal microchip implant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microchip_implant_%28human%29) which can implement the whole [public/private key spiel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), even without the need to keep a members' list on a central computer, and potentially making the bouncer's job easier or even redundant.

Comment: No the monolith is just a coincidence but I looked at the link and I think I may read some Arthur C. Clark now. As for the microchip, I'm not sure about the time period this society is in, so I wanted something a little more compatible with the past. Also, if there's no bouncer then what would stop Bond from cutting the guy's microchipped hand/other body part and using that to enter?

Comment: @donut Ahhh, so the time period is also a factor, you should have mentioned it. Should this question rather be on [Worldbuilding](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I thought about asking this in worldbuilding because of the whole secret society tag, but I though hiding an object sounds more like a lifehack. I'm new here so I'm not too sure about this. If you believe it should be in worldbuilding then I will request it to be moved. Just explain why so I know for future questions. Also the time period thing is just a preference, but mentioning it does make the question sound a lot more of worldbuiling material.

Comment: @donut: worldbuilding is about constructing stories/scenarios and is not limited to tech, may include culture. Maybe ask a similar question but not necessarily presupposing too much :-) See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Incidentally, the time period could be important regarding the metal. Pure Al metal was unknown before about 1825, was much more valuable than gold until about 1889, when it became much more common and cheaper to produce (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aluminium#History). Hmmm, I see a potential subplot right there :-)

Comment: Interesting things about aluminium. So you're saying that my question about how to hide the aluminium piece is a Y to the question "How to provide membership tags to members of my secret society"?

Comment: Could be. Depends on your plot (which I don't know, so I can't say). That's the thing with stories, if you look at what you take as givens, disregard them one at a time, then reconsider your story: will it have any influence on the story? (If no, then it is most probably a "Y") On the other hand, if yes, then you need to see will it make the story better or worse? (Applied lateral thinking).

Comment: Okay so here's the deal. I'm not really making a story or a world. I was just daydreaming one day and thinking about secret societies. I imagined a secret society handing out membership tags in the form of their logos and that's what started my question. That's why I didn't think this was too appropriate for worldbuilding. Because there is no story, no world.

Comment: Sure. I don't think there's any rule that questions on Worldbuilding should be full-fledged stories, or even if they are, get written down any time in future. They seem to be very similar to your daydreaming.

Comment: So should I request this question be moved there?

Comment: As you wish buddy - especially if you haven't gotten an answer to accept, you might get more interest there.

Answer (score 2):

Given the size and (presumed) rigidity of your membership tag, and your criterion that there can't be a trail such as a neck chain (dog tags don't really stand out, and a lot of folks who exercise regularly carry a car key and/or house key that way), many easy hiding places are ruled out.  Protection against pickpockets makes the task harder still, nixing a wallet or just carrying loose in a pocket.

Needing to be able to show the item on short notice, and restow it quickly and easily, further narrows things down.  If you're willing to go to considerable effort and expense, you might be able to have a body modification shop create a skin pouch (say, on one of your pectorals) where the outline of the item would be covered by your body, but the pouch would be accessible through an open shirt collar (not so good for black tie, but fine for shirt and trousers).

Otherwise, if your mouth is big enough (might be marginal, depending on the harshness of the item's corners and edges) you could conceal it in one cheek (preferably inside a protective covering to prevent corrosion and irritation of cheek and gums).  More accessible, no more available to pickpockets, and probably cheaper than a skin pouch.  This one would be greatly simplified if your item were just a little smaller.

Failing in-body methods, modification of your pants to give an access hole inside one pocket would allow a man to store an item this size inside jockey shorts or bikini briefs, in the perineal area.  The doorman probably won't want to touch it if you store it here...

Comment: Well the doorman only has to see it, not touch it, so storing inside underwear would work. The holding in mouth I'm not so sure about. Even if it was smaller, wouldn't it affect my ability to speak?

Answer (score 2):

I have a pair of trousers with a tiny pocket on the right front with the "entry hole" just below the belt. I carry my house key in there. It's a tiny bit difficult to fish it out of there, but it's pretty much impossible to lose it or to have it stolen.

Why not get inspired by that? For the size you're saying you might want to store it horizontally - wide but low pocket - for comfort. Any semi-decent tailor will modify a pair of trousers that way in a blink. Either it can be just below the belt, or to trade a bit of ease for more security directly under it.

It might stand out a little bit, but if you keep a set of keys/phone/handkerchief/... in the main front pocket below it, nobody will notice (they would also need to look directly at your crotch, which most people won't). The only other problem I can see is if you're very fat with a big belly overflowing over your belt - then it will be better camouflaged, but more difficult to pull out.

Comment: Sport clothes often have these little pockets too.

Answer (score 1):

You could sew pockets into the inside of your sleeves and put the object there. It would be impossible to see without turning your sleeve inside out, and therefore impossible to pickpocket. Of course, you would have to do this for every item of clothing you wear with the object.

Answer (score 0):

Armpit is your friend :) If you don't have to put your hands up in the air along the day, just stick it in your left armpit if you are right-handed or the opposite.

Comment: But then I would have to constantly and actively hold my arm slightly pressed to my side. Not the most pleasent thing and it may look suspicious if I never move it.

Comment: @donut What if you put it on a chain around your upper arm/shoulder? It would still be concealed there, but without you having to hold your arm to your side. Whether that would work with short sleeves depends on the string and your clothing. Something like fishing line might be nearly invisible

Answer (score 0):

**Body modification**
To be extreme you can always insert it under your skin.

*Pros*

- Can't be pickpocketed / You can't lose it
- Easily hidden (even in plain sight)
- Access is relatively easily!

*Cons*

- Cannot "just remove" it.
- Might feel uncomfortable? (Never had body modifications but I did have a plate in my arm [broke it] and that felt uncomfortable at times)

Answer (score 0):

An object of the size you describe cannot be hidden on the body unless it mimics a prosthesis. You could hide it in an accessory such as pair of , Buff, gloves, hat, socks or shoes if that is compatible with your character.

If your monolith was smaller it could be part of a pair of glasses or hearing aid.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a wallet Sized item, but you said it should not be "PICKPOCKETed", so what about a modification to your shoe sole (or snicker )
you could carv a slot big enough to fit your item, and conceal the slot with same sole material, something like this http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/mp3-shoes.jpg